# How does Stata treat multiple factor variables in regression?

Tags: regression, stata, categorical-data

I have a city-year level dataset, and run the follow regression with city fixed effects:

```
reg y x i.city
```

I think this is equivalent to generating a dummy variable for each of 300 cities in the data, and run (city 1 as base level):

```
reg y x city2 ... city300
```

However, I need to include year dummies as well. I get the estimates using:

```
reg y x i.city i.year
```

Does anyone know what is going behind this regression **in matrix form**? Is that the same as generating one dummy for each year and run the following?

```
reg y x city2 ... city300 year2 ... year20
```

The reason I want to do this is try to code the command from scratch using matrix operations (X'X)^{-1}(X'y), where X includes the city dummies and year dummies.

Comment: I would recommend searching the Stata blog for threads mentioning OLS. https://blog.stata.com/?s=OLS  There you will see far more details than anyone is likely to give here.

Comment: Thank you, Nick!! This is great resources to know!

Comment: In general yes. Your underlying matrix X must still satisfy the invertibility condition, so in other words no subset of your regressors can be perfectly collinear. In each of your `i.Z` fixed effects expressions, one indicator variable is left out out or else the group of fixed effects would be perfectly collinear with your intercept. This is the general case. If, for example, you have data from one city only in one particular year, then the dummy from either the year or the city much be omitted from X.

Comment: @JR96 thank you for pointing this out! Yes in small dataset collinearity may still exist. Luckily I can recover the estimates by removing one column from each group.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is called corner-point coding for dummy(0,1) variables, where k-1 binary(0,1) variables levels are used for each factor (categorical variable).  If you specify that a constant term should not be used:

```
reg y x i.city i.year, nocon
```

then sum-to-zero constraints coding will be used for binary variable construction, in which there will be a binary variable for both city1 and year1 used in the X matrix.

As you can see (below) when retinol concentration in the diet (retdiet) is regressed on the `male` dummy variable, the coefficient term for constant (y-intcp) is the mean y among females (815), and the coeff for `male` is the delta in y-values between males and females.  Whereas, when both dummy indicators are used - `fem` and `male`, and `, nocon` is specified (after a comma), the values of the regression coefficients for `fem` and `male` are the mean values of y (retdiet) among each group.

[image]